# Ground state Of Gross Pitaevskii Equation

Tags: differential-equations, physics

I want to plot the ground state of Gross-Pitaevskii equation using `NDSolve`. I am using the following code:

```
mu = 0.5;
Nc = 10;
nsol = NDSolve[{-mu ψ0[x] + (1/2) x^2 ψ0[x] - 
   D[ψ0[x], x, x] - 3 Nc Abs[ψ0[x]]^2  ψ0[x] == 0,
  ψ0[-3] == 10, ψ0'[03] == 0}, ψ0, {x, -3, 3}] 

Plot[{ψ0[x] /. nsol}, {x, -1, 01}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

How can I find a good result like in image? 
[image]

Comment: What are the quantities in the graph you're comparing too?  I'd wager the x-axis is radius, in which case: is your differential operator the right one?

Do you really mean to set the boundary conditions at `-3` and `3`?  Notice that your second condition is at `03` rather than `-3`, which is likely a typo.

Comment: (1) The first plot is `ψ0` vs. `x`, but what is the second plot? (2) Is the sign on the cubic term correct? (3) Your code does not reproduce the first plot, but something similar.

Comment: @nadia Where is this drawing for  `Rb87` taken?

Comment: from the paper of F. Dalfovo and S. Stringari (Bosons in anisotropic traps: Ground state and vortices)